SqlBulkCopy into a temp table
I am trying to improve performance of UPDATEs. Following advice in other threads, I am trying to use BulkInsert into a staging table and then UPDATE... WHERE to join against the production table.
The data itself is in a DataTable in VB.net, and I have used SqlBulkInsert to quickly load data from DataTables into SQL Server widely in the past. So my thought was to use a DbCommand to run:
SELECT * INTO ##Projects FROM Projects WHERE 1=0

When I run that code I can see the table is being created when I look in SSMS (which is why I'm using ##). The single DataTable entries in this case is:
Name: "test"
Address: "123 Anywhere St.
City: "St. Louis"

With that done, I tried to run:
   Using S As SqlBulkCopy = New SqlBulkCopy(ConStr)
       S.DestinationTableName = TableName
       S.WriteToServer(DT)
       S.Close()
   End Using

This fails with an error

SqlException: Invalid object name '#Projects'

After a bit of playing around with it, I replaced the ## with TEMP to make TEMPProjects and it worked perfectly. This is the same code I've used many times before.
Looking at threads here, like this one, it seems no special setup is needed for working with temp tables. I'm at a loss, did I miss something?

I'm not sure if using bulk copy with global temp tables works or not but do see the error message references #Projects (local temp table) not ##Projects

I assume by SMS you mean SSMS?

Also if you use the same connection to create the table as the bulk copy then you can use a local temp table rather than a global one.

##Projects and #Projects are not the same table. Global temp tables (e.g.: ##Projects) are visible to all connections for as long as they're in scope of a single connection. Local temp tables (#Projects) exist only on the current connection, which is why you could have multiple connections each with their own independent copy of #Projects.

The linked thread that's using #MyTempTable is executing the command and the SqlBulkCopy operation on a particular connection that it manages itself - it creates the table and then bulk inserts into it on the same connection. The code posted above, however, is creating the SqlBulkCopy using a connection string so that will be a new and independent connection on which #Projects doesn't exist yet.

The problem is that you are giving SqlBulkCopy the connection string, rather than an open connection, so it will open its own separate connection.
This other connection has no relation to the other connection, and therefore cannot see its local temp tables. And if you closed the previous connection then any global temp tables are dropped as well.
You need to use the same connection without closing in between. You also need to make sure that the command that creates the temp table does not use parameters, otherwise it goes via sp_executesql in a separate scope.
Using con As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection(ConStr)
    con.Open()
    Using cmd As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand(createQuery, con)
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    End Using
    Using S As SqlBulkCopy = New SqlBulkCopy(con)
        S.DestinationTableName = TableName
        S.WriteToServer(DT)
    End Using      ' no need to close if you have a Using
End Using


Thanks, I'll try this shortly. I did not drop the connection though, so not sure about that.
